# SharePoint - reporting data from SQL

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, bcs, sql-server, reports

We have got a time tracker website in ASP.NET which is used by employees to record their daily time and work. The data is huge (about 10 years of data and ongoing) and stored in the SQL database.

We want to pick up this data from SQL and create reports on the SharePoint site. Please guide for the way to achieve this. I am guessing we need to make a BCS connection to the SQL server database and then how do we show up charts, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) as it supports displaying data in charts, and integrates with SharePoint.

1. Install SSRS in SharePoint integrated mode, [details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh213532.aspx)
2. Create SSRS reports that connect to your DB, [details](http://fendy-huang.blogspot.fi/2011/02/create-ssrs-report-with-sharepoint-2010.html)

   NOTE! You don't need to use Visual Studio to create the reports, the Report Builder works just fine and is easier as you can just start it from the SSRS Report library in SharePoint.
3. Use SSRS Web Part to display the reports on SharePoint pages, [details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bb326362.aspx)